# Scrum, plan our sprint right. and what if we finished our stories before he sprint ends, what to do?

Tags: scrum, agile, agile-coach

How to plan for our sprint right, so we can deliver our sprint with all agreed stories and also what if we finished all the stories assigned with this sprint, but the sprint isn't finished yet, what shall we do?, do we finish the sprint early?, do we take stories from the product backlog?, do we take a break?

Comment: See the previous thread on this topic: https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/9538/what-if-you-finish-all-stories-before-sprint-ends

Comment: Unless you can explain how this is different.

Comment: Thanks for the reference and the associated answer, but also I was asking about best practice for sprint planing, and how can we as a team plan for our sprint from the beginning to avoid any interruption in the sprint.

Answer (score 0):

In these case, I would usually take additional stories from product backlog. However, this is based on several factors (e.g. How ready are the stories? What is the motivation level of the team to take on additional stories?)

I would suggest that you discuss this with the team, esp tech lead and product owner to get their feedback. Sometimes, it may be necessary to spend the time to clear technical debt / increase test coverage etc.